# Wp All Import Function Editor

Tags: php, wordpress, csv, plugins, wpallimport

I'm trying to import a csv file with wp all import set specific functions to set the sale price and the offer price.
Now I would need to call the function that forms the regular price, inside the function of the offer price, to work on the result and maybe apply a percentage discount.

```
<?php

$GLOBALS['$commissione_paypal_lm'] = 4;
$GLOBALS['$spese_spedizione_moto_lm'] = 10;
$GLOBALS['$spese_spedizione_autocarro_lm'] = 10;
$GLOBALS['$spese_spedizione_varie_lm'] = 7;
$GLOBALS['$pfu_moto_lm'] = 1.50;
$GLOBALS['$pfu_autocarro_lm'] = 4.90;
$GLOBALS['$pfu_varie_lm'] = 2.90;
// First function for regular price,i take variables from csv and global variables
function prezzo_finale( $price = null, $pfu = null, $diametro = null ) {
    if ( !empty( $price ) ) {
        // strip any extra characters from price
        $price = preg_replace("/[^0-9,.]/", "", $price);
        $pfu = preg_replace("/[^0-9,.]/", "", $pfu);
        
        //price ommas and dots fix
        $price = str_replace(",",".",str_replace(".","",$price));
        $pfu = str_replace(",",".",str_replace(".","",$pfu));
        
        // calculate percentage
        $percent = 0;
        if ($diametro != '') {
            $term = term_exists( $diametro, 'pa_diametro', 0 ); 
            if ( $term !== 0 && $term !== null ) { 
                $percent = get_field('percentage', 'pa_diametro_' . $term["term_id"]);
            }
        }
        
        // final price
        $prezzo_finale = $price;
        if (empty( $percent ) ) {
            // Se il campo percentuale è vuoto metto 20% automatico
            $prezzo_appoggio_finale = round((($prezzo_finale + round($prezzo_finale * (20 / 100), 2) + $pfu ) * $GLOBALS['$commissione_paypal_lm'])/100,2) ;
            $prezzo_finale = ($prezzo_finale + round($prezzo_finale * (20 / 100), 2) + $pfu + $prezzo_appoggio_finale);
        }else if ($percent > 0){
            $prezzo_appoggio_finale = round((($prezzo_finale + round($prezzo_finale * ($percent / 100), 2) + $pfu ) * $GLOBALS['$commissione_paypal_lm'])/100,2) ;
            $prezzo_finale = ($prezzo_finale + round($prezzo_finale * ($percent / 100), 2) + $pfu + $prezzo_appoggio_finale);
        }else{
            // Se il campo percentuale è inferiore uguale a zero metto 20% automatico
            $prezzo_appoggio_finale = round((($prezzo_finale + round($prezzo_finale * (20 / 100), 2) + $pfu ) * $GLOBALS['$commissione_paypal_lm'])/100,2) ;
            $prezzo_finale = ($prezzo_finale + round($prezzo_finale * (20 / 100), 2) + $pfu + $prezzo_appoggio_finale);
        }

        // perform calculations
        return $prezzo_finale; 
    }
}
function prezzo_finale_lm( $fifo_ponderato = null, $diametro = null, $settori_codice= null ) {
    if ( !empty( $fifo_ponderato ) ) {
        // strip any extra characters from price
        $fifo_ponderato = preg_replace("/[^0-9,.]/", "", $fifo_ponderato);
        
        //price ommas and dots fix
        $fifo_ponderato = str_replace(",",".",str_replace(".","",$fifo_ponderato));
        
        // calculate percentage
        $percent = 0;
        if ($diametro != '') {
            $term = term_exists( $diametro, 'pa_diametro', 0 ); 
            if ( $term !== 0 && $term !== null ) { 
                $percent = get_field('percentage', 'pa_diametro_' . $term["term_id"]);
            }
        }
        
        // final price
        // moto = 10; vettura 8; isole extra valutare; paypal 3%;
        $prezzo_finale_lm = ($fifo_ponderato);
        if ($settori_codice === 'MOTO' || $settori_codice === 'SCOOTER' || $settori_codice === 'CICLOMOTORI'){
        $spese_spedizione = $GLOBALS['$spese_spedizione_moto_lm'];
        $pfu = $GLOBALS['$pfu_moto_lm'];
        }else if ($settori_codice === 'AUTOCARRO'){
        $spese_spedizione = $GLOBALS['$spese_spedizione_autocarro_lm'];
        $pfu = $GLOBALS['$pfu_autocarro_lm'];
        }else{
        $spese_spedizione = $GLOBALS['$spese_spedizione_varie_lm'];
        $pfu = $GLOBALS['$pfu_varie_lm'];
        }       
        if (empty( $percent ) ) {
            // Se il campo percentuale è vuoto metto 20% automatico
            $prezzo_appoggio_lm = round((($prezzo_finale_lm + round($prezzo_finale_lm * (20 / 100), 2) + $pfu + $spese_spedizione) * $GLOBALS['$commissione_paypal_lm'])/100,2) ;
            $prezzo_finale_lm_paypal = ($prezzo_finale_lm + round($prezzo_finale_lm * (20 / 100), 2) + $pfu + $spese_spedizione + $prezzo_appoggio_lm);
        }else if ($percent > 0){            
            $prezzo_appoggio_lm = round((($prezzo_finale_lm + round($prezzo_finale_lm * ($percent / 100), 2) + $pfu + $spese_spedizione) * $GLOBALS['$commissione_paypal_lm'])/100,2) ;
            $prezzo_finale_lm_paypal = ($prezzo_finale_lm + round($prezzo_finale_lm * ($percent / 100), 2) + $pfu + $spese_spedizione + $prezzo_appoggio_lm);
        }else{
            // Se il campo percentuale è inferiore uguale a zero metto 20% automatico
            $prezzo_appoggio_lm = round((($prezzo_finale_lm + round($prezzo_finale_lm * (20 / 100), 2) + $pfu + $spese_spedizione) * $GLOBALS['$commissione_paypal_lm'])/100,2) ;
            $prezzo_finale_lm_paypal = ($prezzo_finale_lm + round($prezzo_finale_lm * (20 / 100), 2) + $pfu + $spese_spedizione + $prezzo_appoggio_lm);
        }

        // perform calculations
        return $prezzo_finale_lm_paypal; 
                
    }
}
    // Second function for offer price,i would take regular price and work with
function prezzo_offerta_lm() {

        if (prezzo_finale_lm()){
        return prezzo_finale_lm();
        // and for example apply discount as global variable
        }else{
        
        }

        // perform calculations
        
}
?>
```

This is shortcode i use for regular price:

```
[prezzo_finale_lm({fifo_ponderato[1]},{diametro[1]},{settori_codice[1]})]
```

Thank you all for any advice.

```
<?php

// First function for regular price,i take $price variable from imported csv column
function regular_price( $price = null) {
    if ( !empty( $price ) ) {
      
        // final price
        $prezzo_finale = $price;
        // perform calculations as example add markup or paypal commission
        return $prezzo_finale; 
    }
}
// Second function for offer price,where i need to get returned value from first function 
function offer_price($price = null)) {
    if ( !empty( $price ) ) {


        $offer_price = regular_price(); // i need to return here value from first function to perform discount calculation  
        // perform calculations
        return $offer_price; 
                
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: What is the problem or what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @ArnoutPullen i was trying to apply a percentage discount to the price that the first php function returned to me wothout having to do all the calculation insidie the second function, but i couldn’t so i did the calculation again!I’m not a programmer :( anyway thx you for interesting

Comment: Hmm hard to tell what you need the code it's not in english. Try seperating the logic in functions. 1 logic in 1 function. Like calculate_sales_price, calculate_offer_price etc. and use these in the functions you use in wpallimport fields. Basically code you copy/paste or exists on 2 places but that logic in a function.

Comment: @ArnoutPullen I just added some code hoping I made the logic more understandable. Thanks